# How do I uninstall Ubuntu 11.04 from my computer

Tags: uninstall

I installed ubuntu 11.04 on my computer. It is the only operating system on my hard drive.
I decided I want to use windows instead. But when I try to install windows 7 the install program says it doesn't recognize the drive. How can I get ubuntu off of my drive so I can install windows 7? I tried booting up with the ubuntu install cd. This gives me a choice of installations. One of the choices is to delete the partition. But when I select that and then click forward it says that there is no boot sector and can't continue. Please help!

Answer (score 2):

You can boot to your Ubuntu 11.04 CD or GParted Live CD/USB to reformat the entire hard disk to NTFS so Windows 7 installation CD can recognize your harddisk. Then you can reinstall Windows 7.

If you use GParted Live CD/USB you need to download:

1. [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/unetbootin-windows-latest.exe)
2. [GParted Live CD/USB ISO](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gparted/files/gparted-live-stable/)

Use your friends computer (Windows) either to burn the ISO to CD or to run Unetbootin and write the ISO to USB. Follow the instruction from Unetbootin GUI to write the ISO to USB.

Then boot from Ubuntu 11.04 CD or GParted Live CD/USB you've created (set where to boot from BIOS or simply press F12 at startup and choose either CD or USB).

If you use GParted Live CD/USB, you'll welcomed by screen that look like this, choose GParted Live to get started. Otherwise choose Try Ubuntu without installing:

[image: GParted boot screen]

After that you can use GParted GUI to reformat or re-partition your harddisk. Make sure at the top right corner say /dev/sda (it's your harddisk). Check the size of your hard disk.

[image: GParted GUI]

Since you already messed up your harddisk you can't go wrong with this, feel free too explore.

First, delete your current partition and create new NTFS partition.

Second, make sure set the partition's flags to "boot".

[image: Manage partition flags]

Last, press apply.

If the three steps above fail try create ms-dos partition table first then repeat the three steps above.

[image: Create partition ms-dos table]

If you're done with re-partition and reformatting, boot to your Windows 7 installation to install Windows. By now Windows will recognize your hard disk.

Comment: your ubuntu live cd should also have gparted on it